# Blocks Code Completion

Tags: ios, xcode, block

In the below scenario, it does not seem possible to use the tab key to automatically fill in the parameters for the block, instead you have to write them out fully, which is a bit of a pain.

Is there an easier way of doing this?

[image: Code Snipper]

Comment: Double click the autocomplete area.

Comment: Or press `ENTER` instead of `TAB`.

Comment: @carlosfigueira Sorry, I didn't see that you gave this answer already -.-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the auto-fill text highlighted, push `ENTER` and the parameters and block body are filled in for you, as well as an additional bit of auto-fil text that reads `code`.

Comment: **This.** Thanks, even I didn't know this (TBH I rarely use Xcode).